# APEX: apex_application.g_print_error_message problem

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, ora-06550

When i'm using this command

`apex_application.g_print_success_message := '<span style="color:GREEN">Message</span>';`

to show success message is works fine

but when i used the error command `apex_application.g_print_error_message` it gives me this error, anyone can help-me

`ORA-06550: line 10, column 20: PLS-00302: component 'G_PRINT_ERROR_MESSAGE' must be declared ORA-06550: line 10, column 3: PL/SQL: Statement ignored`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`apex_application.g_print_error_message` is a **variable**, so you can set it to a value like '<span style="color:GREEN">Message</span>' but you can't **execute** it as a "command".

Answer (score 1):

No `apex_application.g_print_error_message` is available, only `apex_application.g_print_success_message` is.

Can try `apex_error` package. See [Using APEX_ERROR to manage custom error messages](https://www.apex-at-work.com/2017/01/using-apexerror-to-manage-custom-error.html).